# Get the channel deletor discord py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I wrote the code that works properly but I also want to get the channel deletor to perform that person operation

my code discord py :

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
    await channel.clone(name=channel.name,reason="clone channel")
```

how to get user channel deleted

enjoy ! thanks

Comment: You want to get the user that created the deleted channel? Or what? You're using the `on_guild_channel_delete` event not `on_guild_channel_create`. Please edit your question and clarify the issue.

Comment: yes i,m get user created channel

Comment: The user that created the deleted channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but you're gonna have to fetch the info from the audit logs

If you want the user that **DELETED** the newly deleted channel

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
    async for entry in channel.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.channel_delete):
        print(f"User: {entry.user} deleted channel {channel}")
        # Banning the user
        await channel.guild.ban(entry.user)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Guild.audit_logs`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.audit_logs)
- [`AuditLogAction.channel_delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AuditLogAction.channel_delete)
- [`AuditLogEntry.user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AuditLogEntry.user)

Comment: What if I want to ban the user?

Comment: `await entry.user.ban()`

Comment: h have a error
 inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: You're gonna have to be more specific than that lol

Comment: error ok but Write 'User' object has no attribute 'ban'

Comment: Ah yes that's right, let me edit my answer

Comment: Why do I add a line of code to it, I get an error?